# JSON REST API response convention for property order

Tags: json, rest

Is there a convention for the order the properties in a JSON response appear?

For example, given the response:

```
{
  "name": "Someone",
  "age": 22,
  "country": "Some Country"
}
```

You can see the properties are not ordered in any particular way. One ordering that comes to mind might be alphabetically:

```
{
  "age": 22,
  "country": "Some Country",
  "name": "Someone"
}
```

I want to keep my API responses consistent, so is there any convention toward that matter?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the JSON properties *shouldn't* matter.

You can use alphabetical order or put similar properties next to each other if you think it's easier for a human being to read the JSON document. But there's no difference for a machine.

---

The [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) is one of the documents that define the JSON format. See what is says about objects (highlight is mine):

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

However the order matters for array elements (highlight is also mine):

> An array is an **ordered** sequence of zero or more values.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter because you are accessing them as object key: let value = objectname.keyname
If you are looping (Object.keys(objectname).forEach((item) => {....), the order is not consistent crossbrowser ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)). So there is no reason to care about order aside from logical order when debugging (console.log order).